# $posts = get_posts Wordpress post is not refreshing

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code used to get the most recent post from my blog however it doesn't update when I post a new blog post. Any ideas?

```
            <?php
            $posts = get_posts('numberposts=2&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
            foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?><br>
            <strong><?php the_title(); ?> </strong><br>
            <small><?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?></small>   
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
            <hr>
            <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>
```

Comment: Do **not** use `$posts` as your custom variable, it is a reserved variable in Wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing the following:

$posts = get_posts('numberposts=2&**orderby=date**');